# Generate graphs in PDF file using TCPDF

Tags: tcpdf, svggraph

There are tons of topics on this, none of which have solved my issue. What I'd like to do is simple - generate a bar graph and then embed this graph into a pdf file that I will be generating with a library called [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/).

I'm having no problems generating HTML content using TCPDF but when it comes to generating the graph and including it in the pdf file, I'm having all kinds of issues.

**Generating the graph**

I'm creating the graph using a library called [svggraph](http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph-using.php#reference). Generating the graph is very simple, the only problem is that there are headers being sent through the inclusion of the main class file. When headers are sent, TCPDF cannot generate the PDF document.

My setup now:

generatereport.php - TCPDF generates the pdf document on this page
graph.php - SVGGraph generates the bar graph on this page

I've tried:

- `file_get_contents('graph.php')` from `generatereport.php` - nothing is being output in the pdf report when I use the built in `writeHTML` function that TCPDF offers
- require_once('graph.php') - headers already sent error
- `echo file_get_contents('graph.php')` - Headers already sent, but that was expected. The good news is that the graph was displayed properly.

**Goal (What I'd like to happen)**
TCPDF has a built in `ImageSVG` function that is used for this exact purpose. The first parameter can take a XML string of SVG data; the problem here is that I can't figure out how to return XML data from the `graph.php` page (I've read every documentation page I could find).

Does anyone have any experience using either of these two libraries?

Thanks!

**Edit: Some code**

Graph.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'svggraph/SVGGraph.php';
$graph = new SVGGraph(500, 400);
$graph->Values(1, 4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27); 
$graph->Render('LineGraph', true, true)
?>
```

generatereport.php

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://localhost:8080/vu/graph.php');

if(!empty($file)){
//$pdf->Write(0, $html, '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);
//$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, ''); 
$pdf->ImageSVG('@' . $html, $x=15, $y=30, $w='', $h='', $link='http://www.tcpdf.org', $align='', $palign='', $border=1, $fitonpage=false);
}
```

The `@` symbol tells the function that XML data is being sent to it, as opposed to an SVG file.

Comment: I am not adding it as an answer since I have not tried it. http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph-using.php Section 4 talks about two options to the Render() call to suppress certain return values. More importantly, there is a $Fetch function which is supposed to generate the graph without sending it to the browzer. This may allow you to save the SVG file and read in the ImageSVG command. Also http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a56536508fb1b5aede7d2ed27f56c2353 suggests that the @ option requires the actual SVG data string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `fetch` - See below

```
<?php
require_once 'svggraph/SVGGraph.php';
$graph = new SVGGraph(500, 400);
$graph->Values(1, 4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27); 
$output = $graph->fetch('LineGraph');
?>
```

and then feed it to TCPDF (Since `fetch` without options generates the XML declaration and doctype)
This should generate `$output` of the format:

```
<svg style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1226" version="1.1" height="826"><image transform="matrix(1.0364,-0.3305,0.3305,1.0364,-41.846,108.0143)" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="10" y="10" width="205" height="154" xlink:href="wallpaper.jpg" opacity="1" stroke-width="1"></image><rect transform="matrix(1.0364,-0.3305,0.3305,1.0364,-41.846,108.0143)" x="165" y="114" width="50" height="50" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#C0C0C0" stroke="#000" opacity="0" stroke-width="1"></rect><image transform="matrix(1.1575,0.2385,-0.2385,1.1575,-442.1395,-145.4163)" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="500" y="10" width="205" height="154" xlink:href="wallpaper.jpg" opacity="1" stroke-width="1"></image><rect transform="matrix(1.1575,0.2385,-0.2385,1.1575,-442.1395,-145.4163)" x="655" y="114" width="50" height="50" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#C0C0C0" stroke="#000" opacity="0" stroke-width="1"></rect></svg>
```

Feed it like this

```
$pdf->ImageSVG('@' . $output, $x=15, $y=30, $w='', $h='', $link='http://www.tcpdf.org', $align='', $palign='', $border=1, $fitonpage=false);
```

In line with the comment above from $VSOverFlow.

Of course you can also save the output in a file and then provide the path to the file like so

```
$pdf->ImageSVG($file='images/file.svg', $x=15, $y=30, $w='', $h='', $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=false);
```

Comment: Going to accept this answer, however, it's not technically correct. Going to edit the answer just a touch to make it alright for future viewers.

Comment: Oops sorry some quick typing and overlook errors. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: The fetch method doesn't include graph legend. Is there a way to fix this? I'm sure about the legend options I gave to SvgGraph btw.

Comment: I was giving wrong data to the legend. Problem solved.